# How to mock the GrailsApplication for unit test in a @component object

Tags: unit-testing, grails, groovy, grails-2.2

I have a Component

```
@Component
class SomeComponent {

    @Autowired
    GrailsApplication grailsApplication

    String buildString(String someInfo) {
       return "${grailsApplication.config.my.string}${someInfo}"
    } 
}
```

And a unit test

```
@TestMixin(ControllerUnitTestMixin)
class SomeComponent Tests {


@Test
void test() {
   SomeComponent component = new SomeComponent()

   component.grailsApplication = new Expando()
   component.grailsApplication.config = [config: [my: [string: 'FOO']]]

    assert component.buildString('BAR') == 'FOOBAR'
    }
}
```

When I execute my test I got this error:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object '{}' with class 'groovy.util.Expando' to class 'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.GrailsApplication'
```

So what's the best way to do this?

Comment: You're trying to shove an Expando.class into a property defined as GrailsApplication

Comment: Yep I tried to put a def, but I had some other problem when autowired

Answer (score 0):

Here how I fix it without using a def:

```
SomeComponent component = new SomeComponent(grailsApplication: grailsApplication)
component.grailsApplication.config.my.string = 'FOO'
```

Comment: ControllerUnitTestMixin already declare a grailsApplication mock, you can use that directly instead of creating a new mock.